# How do I make braces in VSCode autocomplete to the same line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to find a solution for this for hours. When I hit enter to autofill a if statement for example, the standard for VSCode C# seems to be this:

[image: VSCode Default if]

Instead, I want the braces to look like this:

[image: VSCode same line if statement]

I've tried to find extensions but they all seem to be deprecated by omnisharp. I've tried creating an omnisharp.json file and placed in my .omnisharp but that has had no effect.

Comment: This seems like a useful tutorial - https://drlongnecker.com/blog/2018/11/vscode-omnisharp-kr-formatting/

Comment: Not that this helps, but newline braces are pretty much an industry-wide standard for C#. I would recommend getting used to it. (I had to do the same for JavaScript, but in reverse.)